# Is there a tool in Linux or GIMP to dynamically lay out a grid of images for scrapbook cutouts?

Tags: gimp, image-processing, krita

I'm looking for a tool that will layout images into grids ***dynamically*** **without altering their proportions**. The purpose would be to make cutting image printouts much faster for scrapbooking. I know a lot of websites can lay out images dynamically, taking each image size into consideration. Is it possible to run a commandline tool to achieve something like this? If possible, a grid without borders would be much better.

There is [an extension for photoshop](http://lumens.se/tychpanel/) that achieves something like this

However, from what I can see, other options in Linux aren't dynamic and require that all images have the same aspect-ratio. It would be ok if there is a little space left over at the end of a page (as in the example). The priority is to maintain each image's aspect ratio whilst using as much space as possible on the page.

An example:

[image: images of different sizes in tiled layout]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30284/discussion-on-question-by-johnpharrell-is-there-a-tool-in-linux-gimp-to-dynamica). Please make sure all important information has been edited into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but [photocollage](https://github.com/adrienverge/PhotoCollage)
seems to do a pretty good job with a bit of tweaking (reducing the border size and hitting regenerate until you're happy).

[image]

Comment: This is very useful!  However it does crop some images, and some are very small. Even so, it's very helpful Thanks for your answer!